# Taking the readings of vibration with low framerate

Tags: python, math, physics, analysis

I have a case in which i have to find a frequency of wavering object with camera (some kind of visual odometry).
There is a limitation: frequency of a filming camera (fps) should be at least twice high as frequency of wavering object.
Are there any possible ways to take the readings of frequencies exceed this limit?
I was thinking about accumulating data and then doing some maths on this

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:python]? Are you using some kind of Python library? Do you already have some Python code but it's just not working as expected? As it stands right now, this seems to be not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to [fit a sine wave to your set of points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902166/fit-sine-wave-to-data) and get it's frequency. Just be careful with the stroboscopic effect.